# Is an ActorRef updated when the associated Actor is restarted by the supervisor?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-supervision, akka-actor

If I create an logging actor like so

```
val logger: ActorRef =
    actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new Logger()))
```

and the logger restarts due to an Exception, my logger stops writing to disk.

I had been sending messages `logger ! msg`

Am I correct in assuming that the ActorRef did not update when the supervisor restarted my logging actor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ActorRef` should be properly updated by Akka to point to the new instance of an actor. The [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/addressing.html) clearly state that:

> A reference pointing to a terminated actor does not compare equal to
>   a reference pointing to another (re-created) actor with the same path.
>   Note that a restart of an actor caused by a failure still means that
>   it is the same actor incarnation, i.e. a **restart is not visible for
>   the consumer of the ActorRef**.

Also [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html):

> When actorOf() is called it assigns an incarnation of the actor
>   described by the passed Props to the given path. An actor incarnation
>   is identified by the path and a UID. **A restart only swaps the Actor
>   instance defined by the Props but the incarnation and hence the UID
>   remains the same.**
>
> The lifecycle of an incarnation ends when the actor is stopped. At
>   that point the appropriate lifecycle events are called and watching
>   actors are notified of the termination. **After the incarnation is
>   stopped, the path can be reused again by creating an actor with
>   actorOf(). In this case the name of the new incarnation will be the
>   same as the previous one but the UIDs will differ.** ...
>
> An ActorRef always represents an incarnation (path and UID) not
>   just a given path. Therefore if an actor is stopped and a new one with
>   the same name is created an ActorRef of the old incarnation will not
>   point to the new one.

That's one of the main advantages of using `ActorRef`s, otherwise it would be much more inconvenient to work with actors.

You need to check your supervisor strategy and make sure that the actor is actually restarted.
Default strategy is:

```
final val defaultStrategy: SupervisorStrategy = {
  def defaultDecider: Decider = {
    case _: ActorInitializationException ⇒ Stop
    case _: ActorKilledException         ⇒ Stop
    case _: Exception                    ⇒ Restart
  }
  OneForOneStrategy()(defaultDecider)
}
```

Thus if you get an `Exception` your actor will be restarted and `ActorRef` should be valid, but if you get other types of `Throwable` then it will be stopped and `ActorRef` will become invalid.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it really well. I just want to add that when an Actor is restarted, it does not finish processing the message that caused the restart. In my case, the actor never sent a message to itself to trigger the next job.

Comment: Thanks for the followup @kliew. I was curious of the reason it was not working as expected in your case.

Comment: If you are within the Actor System you can death watch the ActorRef. But if you want to maintain an ActorRef from the outside, how would you keep this up-to-date?